# Manipulate panel size problem

Tags: manipulate

I have:

```
DynamicModule[{s, v, a},
 s[t_] = 189 - 48 t - 11 t^2 + 2 t^3;
 v[t_] = s'[t];
 a[t_] = s''[t];
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}],
    Arrow[{{s[-6], 0}, {s[10], 0}}],
    Red, PointSize[Large],
    Point[{s[t], 0}]
    },
   PlotLabel -> 
    Grid[{{"Position = ", Round[s[t], .1], "Velocity = ", 
       Round[v[t], .1], " Acceleration = ", Round[a[t], .1]}}, 
     ItemSize -> {{Automatic, {2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 6 -> 4}}, 
       Automatic}]], {{t, -5}, -6, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

Which works just fine. However, when I make this change:

```
DynamicModule[{s, v, a},
 s[t_] = t/(1 + t^2);
 v[t_] = s'[t];
 a[t_] = s''[t];
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}],
    Arrow[{{s[0], 0}, {s[8], 0}}],
    Red, PointSize[Large],
    Point[{s[t], 0}]
    },
   PlotLabel -> 
    Grid[{{"Position = ", Round[s[t], .1], "Velocity = ", 
       Round[v[t], .1], " Acceleration = ", Round[a[t], .1]}}, 
     ItemSize -> {{Automatic, {2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 6 -> 4}}, 
       Automatic}]], {{t, 0}, 0, 8, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

I suddenly have a problem where my manipulate panel is so huge it won't fit on the page. Does anyone see a problem?

Comment: David, perhaps you could highlight the change you made to your code. As it is, we are trying to find Waldo here...

Comment: Try giving `Graphics` the option `AspectRatio -> 0.1, `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following modifications:

- Make your arrow heads larger: `Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}]`;
- The maximum value of the displacement is not attained at $t=8$ here,
  so I'd suggest making the arrow's length dependent on the maximum
  value of the `s` function, e.g. :

  ```
  Arrow[{{s[0], 0}, {MaxValue[s[temp], temp], 0}}]
  ```
- Finally manually change the `AspectRatio` to suit your graphics objects, for instance to `AspectRatio -> 1/2`.

When all those are implemented you get:

```
DynamicModule[{s, v, a},
 s[t_] := t/(1 + t^2);
 v[t_] := s'[t];
 a[t_] := s''[t];
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}], Arrow[{{s[0], 0}, {MaxValue[s[temp], temp], 0}}],
    Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{s[t], 0}]
    },
   PlotLabel -> Grid[{
      {"Position = ", Round[s[t], .1], "Velocity = ", Round[v[t], .1],
        " Acceleration = ", Round[a[t], .1]}
      }, 
      ItemSize -> {{Automatic, {2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 6 -> 4}}, Automatic}
     ],
   AspectRatio -> 1/2
  ],
  {{t, 0}, 0, 8, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great response. The issue is the maximum value of displacement. But what about the temp? It appears blue in my code and does not appear anywhere else in the code? The AspectRatio also works, but I am absolutely clueless as to why so much vertical expansion when I am only drawing a single horizontal line?

Comment: The `AspectRatio` behavior is a good question for which I don't have a firm answer yet. The temp variable is needed because if you used $t$, numerical values for $t$ would be substituted in before the `MaxValue` function could operate; compare with the behavior of this toy example: `Manipulate[MaxValue[1/(1 + t^2), t], {t, 0, 8}]`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out what you were saying.